# stop process if password doesnt same with confirm password php

Tags: php

hi guys im making update for registration . i already have make the coding and password must be update same with confirm password . i already try this. it appear "please check password and confirm password " in alert box. but when i check at database wrong confirm password still in database . example password : admin01 but userconfirm : admin02. how do i stop the process if password doesnt equal confirm password. thank you

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php

include('config1.php');
$username=$_SESSION['username'];


$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$useremail=$_POST['useremail'];
$userdiv=$_POST['userdiv'];
$userdepartment=$_POST['userdepartment'];
$userpass=$_POST['userpass'];
$userconfirm=$_POST['userconfirm'];

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE login SET userid='$userid', useremail='$useremail', userdiv='$userdiv', userdepartment='$userdepartment', userpass='$userpass',userconfirm='$userconfirm' WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
   if ($_POST['userpass'] == $_POST['userconfirm']) 
   {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('UPDATE SUCCESS')
    window.location.href='userMain.php';
    exit();
    </SCRIPT>");
   }
   else
    {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('PLEASE CHECK YOUR PASSWORD AND CONFIRM PASSWORD')
    window.location.href='updateUser.php';
    exit();
    </SCRIPT>");
     }
}    
else
{
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('UPDATE ERROR ')
    window.location.href='updateUser.php';
    exit();
    </SCRIPT>");


}   

?>
```

i think it must put something in else right ? i dont know what to put to end the process if password != confirm password

Comment: You're running your database first before checking whether the confirmation and the password actually match... of course you need to check that *before* you run the database update!

Comment: You are using `exit();` as a Javascript function.. Which doesn't exist

Comment: how to stop the php from running add data into database? did i declare userpass == confirmpass correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating the database in the first place and then you verify if the password doesn't match. You must verify first and if everything is ok update the database.

Another thing you must take care about:

- SQL Injection - your script is very vulnerably.
- `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli_` functions instead.

Code example:

```
if ($_POST['userpass'] != $_POST['userconfirm']) {
    die("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('PLEASE CHECK YOUR PASSWORD AND CONFIRM PASSWORD');
            window.location.href='updateUser.php';
          </SCRIPT>");
}

$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
// ... put all the variables here

$sql="UPDATE login 
      SET userid='$userid'
        , useremail='$useremail'
        , userdiv='$userdiv'
        , userdepartment='$userdepartment'
        , userpass='$userpass'
        , userconfirm='$userconfirm'
      WHERE username='$username'";

if(!mysql_query($sql)) {

    die("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('UPDATE ERROR');
            window.location.href='updateUser.php';
          </SCRIPT>");
}

echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('UPDATE SUCCESS');
        window.location.href='userMain.php';
      </SCRIPT>");
```

Comment: no . i mean i try update one user. and i make sure userpass and confirmpass didnt same. it appear ("please check your password.....") . and it redirect to page that i link to. then i open database to check whether that user is update or not . still it update eventhough userpass != userconfirm . how to stop it from add to database if wrong? yes i know about sql injection . i try to make it one by one. sorry im new